# Using multiple conditions vs array.includes() in an IF statement

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an if statement checking for valid file extensions.

```
if (extension === "jpg" || extension === "jpeg" || extension === "png") {
  console.log("ok");
} else {
  console.log("nok");
}
```

where the variable extension is a string containing the extension of a file.

This works fine but I didn't like how it looked. I changed it a bit.

```
if (["png", "jpg", "jpeg"].includes(extension)) {
  console.log("ok");
} else {
  console.log("nok");
}
```

This looked better to me and I could also store the array of valid extensions in a different variable and add more values to it if needed instead of adding more conditions using OR.

I wish to know if it makes any difference in the performance or generally which one would you prefer.

I would also like to know if any potential errors could be generated using one vs the other. Except for extension being undefined. I am already checking for that earlier.

This code will be running on server-side javascript using node.

Comment: Not that it's likely to occur in your case, but one scenario to keep in mind is that `[NaN].includes(NaN)` gives `true`, but `NaN === NaN` gives false (`.includes()` uses [SameValueZero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality) to test equality). In terms of performance, you can run some benchmarks between the two to see which is faster, I'd imagine it'd be the original `if` with the `||`s, but the performance difference for something like this should be quite negligible.

Comment: For context, the array.includes will be marginally slower but not by much. As you are creating a new dynamic variable with the array this allocates an extra item on the memory heap. In reality though the performance difference will be so minimal it's better to go with what makes the code more readable / maintainable for humans. That's why I would opt for #2. I would also add a condition at the start to avoid undefined values being passed in, like `if (x && myArr.includes(x)) `

Comment: @HJEC: why does that matter? If `undefined` is not in the array, `myArr.includes(undefined)` will be false, as expected. (In fact your proposed code would cause issues with zero or empty strings too)

Comment: @CherryDT I was approaching it from the performance aspect. Short circuiting the logic to avoid starting the loop if there is no value in the first place would save the most compute power. I don't think I follow your last point.  `0` and `''` are both falsy values which would be caught at the start of the if statement. 
Also a reason to check for a truthy value is that if a variable is declared without a value and added to this array, then `[varWithNoValue].includes(undefined)` will be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, 2nd approach is far better - especially when you would create some kind of static member, or const member, something like "const allowedExtensions = ["jpg", "png"] etc.  However, if the array's purpose is to contain allowed/disallowed values, use Set instead of array. Set are way faster when checking if they contain a value - Set has .has(value) method that is equivalent to Array.includes(), but it's faster. So yes, it's perfectly fine to store it somewhere (i recommend const or static somewhere) and again, Set will be better for checking if element is in it, than using an array.
Example:

```
const allowedExtensions = new Set(["jpg", "png"]);

if (allowedExtensions.has("jpg") {
  console.log("ok");
}
```

Comment: While it's generally true that Sets have amortized `O(1)` lookup but arrays only have `O(n)`, with this few elements the performance difference is probably negligible. I'd assume a Set may even be slower here because of the overhead of hashing, although I have no data to back this up.

Comment: I agree that hashing could make initialization slower than array, but once initialized and stored as a static or const i(n a way that it will not be initialized over and over when accessed), it will be faster than array when it comes to has/includes.

Comment: Well actually, no. Even if the set isn't initialized over and over again, the key to be looked up still has to be hashed every time. I created some benchmarks (tinyurl.com/2jxjndzb) to test it out: the results are a bit different every time it's run, so *neither of them* is faster. For cases where there are significantly more elements to check, I'd recommend using a set, but in this case I'd stick to an array...